# ScalaJsonCombinators how to read JSON to Map[String, CaseClass]

Tags: json, scala, playframework

The JSON I need to parse is like

```
{
"state": "active",
"id": "11775",
"translations": {
  "de_CH": {
    "name": "Spiegel",
    "url": "spiegel-sale"
  },
  "fr_CH": {
    "name": "Miroirs",
    "url": "promo-miroirs-femme"
  }
 }
```

In the translations, the keys **de_CH** and **fr_CH** are not known in advance. The other keys are known.

For me the translations object can be as modelled as a dictionary.

Here are the case class

```
case class Category(
  id: String,
  order: Int,
  translations: Map[String, NodeTranslation]
)

case class NodeTranslation(name: String, url: String)
```

The ScalaJsonCombinators reads are

```
implicit val categoryReads = Json.format[Category
implicit val nodeTranslationReads = Json.format[NodeTranslation]]
```

**How to read Map[String,NodeTranslation] in JSON ?**

I didn't find anything for a Map there : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#complex-reads

Answer (score 1):

Well that's how:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Category(
  id: String,
  order: Int,
  translations: Map[String, NodeTranslation]
)
case class NodeTranslation(name: String, url: String)

implicit val nodeTranslationReads = Json.format[NodeTranslation]
implicit val categoryReads: Reads[Category] = (
  (__ \ 'id).read[String] and
  Reads.pure[Int](123) and // your example json doesn't contain an order member so I'm not sure what you expect here
  (__ \ 'translations).read[JsObject].map { obj =>
    obj.value.mapValues(_.as[NodeTranslation]).toMap
  }
)(Category.apply(_, _, _))
```

And now testing that in the repl:

```
val js =
  """
    |{
    |"state": "active",
    |"id": "11775",
    |"translations": {
    |  "de_CH": {
    |    "name": "Spiegel",
    |    "url": "spiegel-sale"
    |  },
    |  "fr_CH": {
    |    "name": "Miroirs",
    |    "url": "promo-miroirs-femme"
    |  }
    | }
    |}
  """.stripMargin
val json = Json.parse(js)

json.as[Category]
```

the result is:

```
Category(11775,123,Map(de_CH -> NodeTranslation(Spiegel,spiegel-sale), fr_CH -> NodeTranslation(Miroirs,promo-miroirs-femme)))
```

Note that if you want to create a formatter for `Category`, you have to use:

```
(__ \ 'translations).format[JsObject].inmap(...)
```

nb: I really love play-json it's not always easy to use but I've yet to find a case where I can't get it to do what I need.